# Single quotes in JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking at the Google Maps API tutorial, and I see this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{name:'maps', version:3, other_params:'sensor=false'}]}"></script>
```

Why is `modules` wrapped in single quotes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a good practice to wrap keys in quotes, even though not strictly required, in order to avoid the possibility of conflicts with [JavaScript reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words).

Imagine if you had `class` instead of `modules` - `class` happens to be a reserved word in JavaScript, even though it is not actually used in the current specification.

Comment: @stone if you are happy with Daniel's response you should accept it by clicking the green tick on the left.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: I didn't intend to say that reserved works are invalid identifier names. Only that it is often considered good practice to wrap key in quotes (especially for backward compatibility with ES3).

Comment: @DanielVassallo Fair enough. Just be aware that in ES5 this is no longer the case. (Also, reserved words in ES3 are different from those in ES5.)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, in most [JSON](http://json.org/) implementations (because it's actually a JSON string), like jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), it's obligatory to put all strings, whether they represent values or properties, within double-quotes.

Comment: The "double quotes" is the correct way to go for JSON, since they are mandatory in the JSON spec.

Answer (score 1):

[The currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788251/96656) is incorrect — reserved words are valid identifier names, so they’re allowed as unquoted property names in JavaScript.

From [***Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript***](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties), my write-up on the subject:

> Quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal or [a valid identifier name](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).
>
> […]
>
> Bracket notation can safely be used for all property names.
>
> […]
>
> Dot notation can *only* be used when the property name is a valid identifier name.

I also made a tool that will tell you if any given property name can be used without quotes and/or with dot notation. Try it at [mothereff.in/js-properties](http://mothereff.in/js-properties).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's not *required* unless:

1. The property is named the same as a keyword/reserved
2. The property has special chars
3. The object is intended to be used as JSON