# Send data with ajax, return json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to send a string and return json.

This works but it doesn't return json code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getFeed.php",
    type: "post",
    data: myString
});
```

When I want it to return a json string, it gives me an error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getFeed.php',
    type: "post",
    data: {string1: "testdata", string2: "testdata"},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
});
```

For some reason the server doesn't recieve any data.

How am I supposed to write this? (i want to send 2 strings)

Comment: Whether you get json back or not will depend on the server-side part, i.e. getFeed.php ... But you have a trailing comma: `timeout: 5000,` which is a problem.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console log ?

Comment: I receive array(0) when i use `echo var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @developerwjk I actually have a success and error field after that, removed it to make it a little cleaner, forgot the comma

Comment: also, if you read docs, error handler won't fire for jsonp either. You probaly don't want to use `jsonp` since path is to local server

Answer (score 1):

JSONP does not allow using `POST` method as it is really just a script request.

Since path used is relative (same domain) I suggest you use `json` datatype since `jsonp` is intended for cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The keys are not, in fact, required to be in quotes. I was mistaken there. However, it still seems to be best practice, to avoid potential future issues.

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "getFeed.php",
    "type": "post",
    "data": {"string1": "testdata", "string2": "testdata"},
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    "jsonp": "jsoncallback",
    "timeout": 5000,
});
```

Comment: No actually i need to use it like this: `data: {username: usernameVar, userID: userIDVar},`

Comment: then it would be `"username": usernameVar, "userID": userIDVar`. "username" and "userID" are strings.

Comment: quotes are not needed on object keys in javascript as long as there are no special characters in property names. Thus this answer is invalid

Comment: @charlietfl Really? I never knew this. Any chance you could point me to some reference?

Comment: @charlietfl The first result returned from just googling around... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys it sounds like it's not _required_, but is best practice

EDIT: It also looks like jquery has, as of jquery 1.4, required double-quoted keys on the JSON, or else it silently throws an error. References http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ and https://forum.jquery.com/topic/json-on-jquery-1-4

Comment: don't confuse a javascript object with JSON. The data option of ajax is an object

Comment: JSON is an object too. I'm afraid I don't understand the difference. And in this case, the double quotes would very clearly convey that the keys are not javascript _variables_, but are meant to be taken as string literals.

Comment: no, JSON is a string data transfer format. Object keys are not variables either, they are keys. You are creating an object  literal that subsequently will be converted to form encoding and not even JSON

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose this isn't JSON. Even in javascript objects, however, it's considered best practice to enclose keys in quotes. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788236/single-quotes-in-javascript-object-literal) as well as [Mathias Bynens' comment on the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes) for reference.

Comment: still subjective, look at objects in jQuery style guide  http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#object-and-array-expressions  `Property names only need to be quoted if they are reserved words or contain special characters:`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first your ajax syntax doesnt seem to be right.

Lets suppose you want to send two strings `stringA` and `stringB`. Your php file is `getFeed.php`.

Your ajax would look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
               type : "POST",
               url : "getFeed.php",
               data : {firstVar:stringA,secondVar:stringB},
               dataType: "json",
               success : function(data){

                         // Here you receive the JSON decoded.
                        var mesage = data.msg;
                 }  
        });
```

Inside `getFeed.php` you would receive the strings like this:

```
$firstString = $_POST['firstVar'];
$secondString = $_POST['secondVar'];
```

And when you return the JSON object to the ajax from `getFeed.php`, this is how you would do it:

```
$myArray = array("msg"=>"Hello World", "another"=>"thing");
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

So lets go back to the ajax function, where the success part is, you receive a parameter `data`, and if you want to access the 'msg' and 'another', you would so like this:

```
       success : function(data){

                         var first = data.msg;
                         var second = data.another;
               }
```

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around the keys in the data JSON.

Comment: The quotes around the keys in the data JSON? o.O

Comment: Tried this, it now goes straight to the error field of the ajax call

Comment: Debug, test wether it gets to (or can find) the php file (log it),